# How to check h5py version in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check the h5py version I am using in python.
I have tried `h5py.version` but this just takes me to a file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `h5py.__version__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get versions is `pip show 'package_name'`

`pip show h5py`

Answer (score 3):

You can see the version by running:

```py
import h5py
print(h5py.__version__)
```